# measure time difference

Tags: c++, time, localtime

I want to measure in milliseconds how much time there is between when I start my application and another time, for example 16:00 o'clock. What is the best way to do this?

I looked around "clock" function but it's not what I need.

Operating system: Win NT and above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look up [gettimeofday](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html) for POSIX systems, and [timeGetTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757629(v=vs.85).aspx) for Windows.

Edit: Seems the OP was asking for code to compare current time/date against another time/date. The following snippet demonstrates how to get current date and time on Windows:

> ```
>  #include <Windows.h>
>  #include <stdio.h>
>
>  void main()
>  {
>      SYSTEMTIME st;
>      GetSystemTime(&st);
>      printf("Year:%d\nMonth:%d\nDate:%d\nHour:%d\nMin:%d\nSecond:%d\n"
>        ,st.wYear,st.wMonth,st.wDay,st.wHour,st.wMinute,st.wSecond);
>  }
> ```

And here's how to compute the difference between two SYSTEMTIME objects:

> ```
>  #include <windows.h>
>  #include <iostream>
>
>  // Return time difference in units of 100 us.
>  _int64 Delta(const SYSTEMTIME st1, const SYSTEMTIME st2) {
>   union timeunion {
>       FILETIME fileTime;
>       ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
>   } ;
>
>   timeunion ft1;
>   timeunion ft2;
>
>   SystemTimeToFileTime(&st1, &ft1.fileTime);
>   SystemTimeToFileTime(&st2, &ft2.fileTime);
>
>   return ft2.ul.QuadPart - ft1.ul.QuadPart;
> }
>
> int main() {
>   SYSTEMTIME t1 = {0}, t2 = {0};
>   t1.wDay = 10;
>   t1.wMonth = 4;
>   t1.wYear = 2009;
>
>   t2.wDay = 12;
>   t2.wMonth = 4;
>   t2.wYear = 2009;
>
>   _int64 i = Delta(t1, t2);
>   std::cout << "times are " << i / 10000000 << " seconds apart\n";
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Those two samples should give you the tools to do what you need.

Comment: @Julio IMHO. This is the cleanest and simplest implementation to solve this problem I have seen from many solutions.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a POSIX system, you can use [`gettimeofday(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gettimeofday):

```
struct timeval start, end;
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
...
gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

// Watch out for overflow!
int delta_milliseconds = 1000 * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec)/1000;
```

If you're on Windows, you can use [`GetTickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
DWORD start, end;
start = GetTickCount();
...
end = GetTickCount();
int delta_milliseconds = end - start;
```

But but aware that `GetTickCount` only has a resolution of about 10-16 ms.  If you need more precision, use [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead:

```
// Error-checking omitted for expository purposes
LARGE_INTEGER freq, start, end;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
...
QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
double delta_milliseconds = (double)(end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / freq.QuadPart * 1000.0;
```

Comment: Hey thanks Adam but this counts time elapsed between calls. what i need is to count the current system time, say 12:30 and measure how many milliseconds are between 12:30 and a pre defined time, say 16:00